# extract information from map values

Tags: terraform

I have a local variable which looks like:

```
locals {
  teams = {
    "team1" = {
      "username1"                  = ["role1", "role2", "role3"],
      "username2"                  = ["role1", "role2"]
     },
     "team2" = {
      "username3"                  = ["role1", "role2", "role3"],
      "username4"                  = ["role1", "role2"]
     }
  }
}
```

So I am creating users and attaching roles to each user as per the team's information, and my module is expecting username, roles, and team_name.

How do I parse the above local variable to get username, roles attached to it and team it belongs?

my module looks like this

```
module "redshift_user" {
  for_each = local.teams

  source                   = "../../../modules/redshift-users"
  username                 = keys(each.value)
  roles                    = values(each.value)
  team_name                = each.key
}
```

getting team_name is easy as the key would be team_name but getting each username and role under the team is where I am struggling, any help would be much appreciated. I have to call the module for each username so that it creates a user in DB.

***Note***: The username will be unique under each team.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Do you get an error? What does the module look like?

Comment: so current code gets the entire key as list with keys(each.value) but I want the module to be called for each users. So module expect username, roles, team_name as input.
The problem here I am facing is I am not able to find a way to pass each username and associated roles and the team it belongs to the module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your `teams`:

```
locals {
  teams_flat = merge(flatten([
    for team, members in local.teams: {
      for member, roles in members: 
            "${team}-${member}" => {
                 "team" = team
                 "username" = member
                 "roles" = roles
             }
   } 
  ])...) # do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then:

```
module "redshift_user" {
  for_each = local.teams_flat

  source                   = "../../../modules/redshift-users"
  username                 = each.value.username
  roles                    = each.value.roles
  team_name                = each.team
}
```

Comment: I performed smiliar to below and it worked

```locals {

  user_list = flatten([for team, value in local.teams :
    flatten([for username, roles in value :
      {
        "team" : team,
        "username" : username,
        "roles" : roles
      }
    ])
  ])
}```